# winreg parameters to retrieve PATH in Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, registry, winreg

To retrieve the contents of the `%PATH%` variable on a Windows 10 Home edition machine, what values should be used for the `key`, `subkey`, and `name` parameters in the following Python script?

```
import winreg

def _get_reg_value(key, subkey, name):
    """Return registry value specified by key, subkey, and name.

    Environment variables in values of type REG_EXPAND_SZ are expanded
    if possible.
    """

    key = _winreg.OpenKey(key, subkey)
    try:
        ret = _winreg.QueryValueEx(key, name)
    except WindowsError:
        return None

    else:
        key.Close()
        if ret[1] == _winreg.REG_EXPAND_SZ:
            return expandvars(ret[0])

        else:
            return ret[0]
```

Note that we are not using `os.environ` here because we need to interact with the permanent path values, not just with the runtime values that are exposed by `os.environ`.

The code example above is from [this link](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/57898/_winreg.REG_EXPAND_SZ) .  I am using it to study how to interact with the Windows Registry programmatically using Python.

---

**Failed Attempt:**

---

When I call the above function using the following syntax in a `.py` file run from Windows CMD, all that is returned is a blank line in Windows CMD, followed by a command prompt.  As if nothing has happened.

```
key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager')

_get_reg_value(key, 'Environment', 'Path')
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "permanent path values"?  Where did you get the registry key path shown in your "Failed Attempt"?  On my machine, that key path doesn't exist.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy  I got that key path from `regedit`.  What is more, I am proceeding with PowerShell temporarily to prove out the concept, and this key path works with the PowerShell version of the code.  So I think somehow the problem is with how Python is interacting with the registry.  ...  Separately, per the permanent part, `os.environ` only temporarily changes the path while the calling Python script is running.  By contrast, changing the registry key will change the path globally forever until something else changes the registry key again.

Comment: Like I said, that key doesn't exist on my machine (so sayeth RegEdit).  Relying on undocumented bits of registry settings is going to cause portability problems.  Please describe the problem you're trying to solve.  Also, are you using a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Python?  Are you running from a process that has permission to access that part of the registry?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy To confirm that the key does not exist on your computer, please take 2 minutes to open PowerShell **as an administrator** and run the following command in PowerShell `(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH).path`  .  Note to get the command to work, you may need to also run `Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted` in PowerShell first.  The result should be a printout of the PATH, which in this OP I am trying to address via Python.

Answer (score 1):

If Python's [winreg](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html) library simply wraps the corresponding Windows APIs, then you have to [open each component of the key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopenkeyw).  You can't say:

```
winreg.OpenKey(winreg::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "FOO\\BAR")
```

Instead, you first have to open FOO and then open BAR:

```
foo_key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "FOO")
bar_key = winreg.OpenKey(foo_key, "BAR")
```

This is likely the root of your problem.

But there may be more to it.  After making such a change, you're supposed to broadcast a [WM_SETTINGCHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settingchange) so that other processes (like the shell) know to invalidate their caches and reread the system settings.  It's likely the PowerShell commandlet does that automatically.

There can be other issues, too.  For example, if you're running a 32-bit Python on a 64-bit OS, you might run into Registry redirection, depending exactly on which part(s) of the hive you're trying to access.

To clarify, what you're calling the "permanent path values" is part of the [system environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/environment-variables).  If you have privileges (e.g., running as Administrator), you are correct that you can modify the path from the system environment block at those keys.

The system merges the user environment variables with the system environment variables.  If PATH is defined in both environments, the final PATH is the concatenation of the system values followed by the user values.  For other variables with both a system and a user definition (e.g., TMP), the user values are used.

Child processes inherit a copy of their parent process's environment.  So, even with a WM_SETTINGCHANGE broadcast, they probably won't update their path to reflect changes you've made to the system environment block.